# Laravel isset always returning false on nested relations

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, isset

Consider the following scenario:
I have an Eloquent model named Order which has a Line Item and a Line Item Totals defined as the following (simplified for the question):

```
class Order extends Eloquent {
    public function lineitem() {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Models\LineItem','id','lineitem_id');
    }
}
class LineItem extends Eloquent {
    public function totals() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\\Models\\LineItemTotal",'lineitem_id');
      }
}
```

When I perform `dd($order->lineitem->totals)` I receive the data correctly:

```
Collection {#530 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => LineItemTotal {#506 ▶}
    1 => LineItemTotal {#531 ▶}
    2 => LineItemTotal {#522 ▶}
    3 => LineItemTotal {#508 ▶}
    4 => LineItemTotal {#509 ▶}
    5 => LineItemTotal {#510 ▶}
    6 => LineItemTotal {#511 ▶}
  ]
}
```

However, when I perform:

```
dd(isset($order->lineitem->totals));
```

I receive:

```
false
```

This is really bugging my mind and so far my guess is that somewhere along the process there is a protected attribute that prevents `isset()` or `empty()` from accessing it and hence returning `false` (although both methods are defined as public).

Any idea as to why this is happening and how to resolve it? one thought I hade is to override the `isset()` with a magic method but I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: use count() > 0.Then foreach and then isset

Comment: @Bugfixer, I believe count() will trigger an error if there is no lineitem at all (which is possible)

Answer (score 0):

When isset() return false, it may be getting error when lookup in "lineitem" or "totals" (relationship) because of empty value lookup.

Solutions is to break them apart and put try catch exception

```
// part 1
try {
  $lineitem = $order->lineitem;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $lineitem = [];
}

// part 2
try {
  $totals = $lineitem->totals;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $totals = [];
}

dd($totals);
```